# 301 Redirect with limited access to site

Tags: redirect, meta-tags, http-status-code-301

I've recently developed a new website for a local charity that organises an annual sporting event. With the event coming up in a few weeks we approached the previous/existing 'dev' company to either redirect the domain to the new site/server or transfer the domain to us.

This other 'company' is refusing to do anything, simply because they want to force the charity to stay with them, so that they get good local publicity.

So, we've purchased a new domain for the site but need to redirect the old site to the new one. Unfortunately the system the old web company uses is very poor and cumbersome. It also only give us access to files which form the content of a given page. It doesn't however give us any access to the site template / style elements of the site, nor does it give us access to things like .htacess file(s).

So, at the moment the best I've come up with is using the existing systems single input for the site description, to force in a meta refresh that will bump users over to the new domain/site. However, this isn't going to result in a permanent 301 redirect for users or search engines.

As such, I'm desperately hoping to come up with a way to force a 301 for all pages without directly accessing every page content file and manually adding in some sort of redirect.

Comment: Isn’t the old domain owned by the charity, but by the previous web dev company? If the WHOIS says that the charity owns it, the charity should be able to contact the domain registrar to get access. This would allow them to point the old domain to the new site.

Comment: True, but it's never that simple. Also the event is in 5 weeks. Furthermore, anyone whos ever worked with a charitable organisation knows that trying to get the multi-headed beast to do the most simple thing in a timely manner is nigh on impossible. Plus, the domain details are all registered to a 3rd party who works with the current 'dev company'. This only feasible option at this stage is a redirect, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay. What exactly allows you the limited access to the old site? Can you add full HTML in the `body`, but in the `head` you can only edit the `content` of a `meta`-`description` element (and you managed to add a `refresh` element there)? -- You might want to flag your question and ask for migration to [webmasters.se]; I think it’s more appropriate there, as SEO is relevant.

Comment: It's a crappy homemade type CMS. Tbh, I was hoping there might be some little known method for doing a 301 redirect via the metatags or JS.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some crappy sitewide one size fits all unescaped metatag implementation, I was able to inject an additional metatag with a redirect to the new domain.